# Google Spreadsheet setBackgroundColors() "Deprecated"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A gs I have been using in the past to check for duplicates, is no longer working. The script would check all cells in the spread sheet if any were identical it would highlight all their occurrences green. I also had another function that would revert all the cells back to white.

setBackgroundColors() has been deprecated; people have been recommended to now use setBackground(). The script still doesn't work...

Here is my gs, make a copy and fiddle with it. Many Thanks...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UELTxZRZPKQKU9NsQwNefvdxJDM0xDt8904sZy3etoY/edit#gid=0

Here is the script.

```js
/**
 * Retrieves all the rows in the active spreadsheet that contain data and logs the
 * values for each row.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    Logger.log(row);
  }
};

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the readRows() function specified above.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Check Directory",
    functionName : "CheckDirectory"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

function CheckDirectory() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var numColumns = data[0].length;
 
  var formats = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    formats[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      formats[i][j] = 'white';
      if (data[i][j] != '') {
        values.push([data[i][j], i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
  var numValues = values.length;
   
  for (var k = 0 ; k < numValues - 1; k++) {
    if (formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] == 'white') {
      for (var l = k + 1; l < numValues; l++) {
        if (values[k][0] == values[l][0]) {
          formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] = 'green';
          formats[values[l][1]][values[l][2]] = 'green';
        }
      }
    }
  }
     
  dataRange.setBackground(formats);
};

function resetCheckDirectory() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var numRows = data.length;
  var numColumns = data[0].length;
 
  var formats = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    formats[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      formats[i][j] = 'white';
      if (data[i][j] != '') {
        values.push([data[i][j], i, j]);
      }
    }
  }
  var numValues = values.length;
   
  for (var k = 0 ; k < numValues - 1; k++) {
    if (formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] == 'white') {
      for (var l = k + 1; l < numValues; l++) {
        if (values[k][0] == values[l][0]) {
          formats[values[k][1]][values[k][2]] = 'white';
          formats[values[l][1]][values[l][2]] = 'white';
        }
      }
    }
  }
     
  dataRange.setBackground(formats);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setBackgrounds()`. With an `s` since it's a method that applies multiple background colors to multiple cells

Comment: I have tried setBackgrounds() and setBackground()                                  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: No error message, turns out when I tried setBackgrounds() before I had my colors "GREEN" and "WHITE" in all caps. Just tried setBackgrounds() again with them in lowercase and it is working. Problem solved.

Comment: The only thing that has always bugged me about the script is how long it takes to revert the whole table back to white. Instead of selecting them all at once, I got it doing a cycling process. Which is inefficient; couldn't figure out how to select all.

Comment: do you want all the cells to turn white without any condition ?

Comment: yeah no condition, basically clicking the button sets it all back to white.

Comment: then use simply this :  `sheet.getDataRange().setBackground("#FFF");`

Comment: ???function resetCheckDirectory() { sheet.getDataRange().setBackground("#FFF");};

Comment: you should of course define `sheet` beforehand ;-), just like you did in your code. The idea is to use `setBackground(color string)` to a whole range with a single argument to set the same color everywhere.

Comment: I can't seem to get the script to select the sheet I even tried with a defined ranged name.

Comment: scrap all the looping, you don't need 'formats' to be an array. as @Serge says, it should be a single string, e.g. 'white'